# How to encode accents to query Mediawiki API in R?

Tags: r, utf-8, character-encoding, diacritics, mediawiki-api

I have no problem to query Mediawiki API of French Wikipedia for strings without accents:

```
string <- 'chien'
string <- stringi::stri_enc_toutf8(string, is_unknown_8bit = FALSE, validate = FALSE)
apiQuery <- paste0('https://fr.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=xml&titles=', string)
page <- xml2::read_xml(apiQuery)
```

> {xml_document}
>
> [1] \n  \n    \n  \n  \n    <page _idx="2736914" pageid="2736914 ...

but I have problem for strings with accents:

```
string <- 'être'
string <- stringi::stri_enc_toutf8(string, is_unknown_8bit = FALSE, validate = FALSE)
apiQuery <- paste0('https://fr.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=xml&titles=', string)
page <- xml2::read_xml(apiQuery)
```

I receive the following error :

> Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 400.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to encode the query in HTML escapes:

```
page <- xml2::read_xml(URLencode(apiQuery))
```

This changes the `"ê"` to `"%C3%AA"`.